# Mysql console client do not take non-ASCII characters

Tags: mysql, locale, input-language, encoding, internationalization

I use Ubuntu 15.04 and mysql client 5.6
My locale is

```
$ locale
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=ru:en
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

When I use Terminal and input cyrillic characters, it works perfect. But, when I run mysql console client and try to input them, nothing happens.

I googled identical bugs in 2014 with Fedora, but didn't found any fix.

Comment: What namely did you try? `--default-character-set=` as mentioned in mysql(1), or else?

Comment: --default-character-set= is not working. I have same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved same problem by updating mysql-client package.
I downloaded .deb package from mysql.com, which contains mysql repositories, and installed new mysql-client package.
This link should help: [A Quick Guide to Using the MySQL APT Repository](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/).